# Anyway to view SVN Checkouts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-checkout

Is there any way to view a log of who/when does a checkout of a repository?

Commits are obviously logged.

This would be used to monitor who has checked a project to help with work tracking.

Comment: Why would checkouts be tracked? That would serve no purpose for version control, because it changes nothing.

Comment: I don't know how to access to your repos but there's a solution: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.operational-logging.html

Comment: @teng what exactly this information will give you?

Comment: @uzsolt - thanks. Put this as an answer and I'll mark as accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a solution in some cases: [high-level logging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.operational-logging.html).

> To enable high-level logging in svnserve, you need only use the
>   --log-file command-line option when starting the server, passing as the value to the option the file to which svnserve should write its
>   log output.
>
> `$ svnserve -d -r /path/to/repositories --log-file /var/log/svn.log`